# XSL "for-each" using Javascript ID won't output anything

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, foreach

So I have an XML, XSL and Javascript file. I won't copy my entire XML file as it is far too big, but here is the code in question:

```
<courses>
  <course>
    <c_info>
      <c_code>U65</c_code>
      <c_title>Computer Science</c_title>
    </c_info>
```

I then have a Javascript file that has these parameters

```
function transform(message) {
transformXML("xml_courseinfo.xml", "course_menu.xsl", "main_body", "sid", message)
}
```

Then in my XSL file, I have these lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="sid" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <title>Cross Browser Compatible Parameter Passing</title>

        <!-- javascript processor for loading the xslts with the xml-->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="processxml.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="main_body">
          <h1>Course Main Menu</h1>
          <xsl:for-each select="courses/course/c_info[c_code=$sid]"> 
            <Strong>Course Name:</Strong> <xsl:value-of select="c_title"/> <hr /> 
          </xsl:for-each> 
        </div>
      </body>  
    </html>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Nothing displays at all, I am giving it the correct path and the Course code (`c_code`) is unique, can anyone help me understand the problem here?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Are you trying to do the XSL transform browser side?  If not what server platform are you using?

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Yes, everything is being done locally.

Comment: Hmm, that might be the problem. It's usually done on the server so you can control the transformation on a single platform.  In the browser every XSLT engine is different.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth I have tried multiple browsers, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Try to pull it apart a little, perhaps try output every course first, then just those with the matching $sid.  Try forcing a default value in the parameter as follows <xsl:param name='sid'>U65</xsl:param>, then try it without.  How are you getting the $sid value to the XSL in your transformation function?

Comment: Your XSLT seems correct. IE has a [transformNodeToObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766561.aspx) and the other browsers support [transformToDocument()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_the_mozilla_javascript_interface_to_xsl_transformations#transformToDocument). You would have to deal with that before processing. How is your `transformXML()` function implemented?

Comment: When you say *nothing shows at all* does that include the whole `<html>` block is just the `<xsl:for-each>` list empty? Is `<courses>` the root node of your XML?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is displaying, then either the XSLT isn't executing at all, or you're supplying the wrong value of $sid. You can easily discover which of these is true by having the stylesheet output some constant text, e.g.

```
<h1>Transformation output for sid=<xsl:value-of select="$sid"/></h1>
```